# Accessing documentDB on host in docker contains

Tags: docker, azure-cosmosdb

1. I have an docker ASP.Net core webapi in a docker container running.
2. I Have on the Host machine installed the local documentDB emulator

So when I try to use `http://localhost:8081` to access the emulator, it won't work. I think that is "correct" because localhost is not the host system. So what I want is to access the `http://localhost:8081` from the parent host.

I tried to use the ip from the parent host and the hostname from the parent host with the same error that the host / emulator cannot be reached, but I can ping the host from the container.

The emulator is up and running and I Disabled all firewalls (in the host).

My dockerfile (very basic):

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.0.1
ARG source  
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-bin/Release/PublishOutput} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Portal.UserProfile.dll"]
```

So what do I wrong? Or is it possible to run documentDb emulator in a docker host?

Comment: Currently the local emulator works off the loop back IP (i.e. 127.0.0.1) so its not possible to connect externally.  You could possibly install the local emulator on the docker container running ASP.NET?

Comment: But the documentdb has an msi installer.... Does this run on a linux image or does there exist a windows docker?

Comment: I have the same issue. I could connect to the host using the /AllowNetworkAccess flag when starting the emulator, but I'm having problems with the self signed certificate, which is unrecognized in the container. Any idea on making it work?